# Select statement is not working in python

Tags: python-3.x, oracle11g

I was using oracle 11g database  with python3.6 and using cursor trying to select the columns from the database using select statement.

```
     import cx_Oracle
     con=cx_Oracle.connect("sys/ornnsn@localhost/sysdba")
     cur=con.cursor()
     cur.execute("SELECT * from Employer")
     cur.fetchall()
     print(cur.rowcount)
     con.close()
```

Rows count is 0 as the output but there are rows into the table using sqlplus it can be viewed.Please help me !!

Comment: Is that table really owned by SYS?  If not there should be a schema name in front of Employer.

Comment: Dictionary parameter is been changed so i think definitely it is owned by sys. If i am wrong please correct me and please also let me know how to see schema for this

Comment: @LakshayGupta - How do you expect Jon Heller to tell you if your table is owned by SYS, and if it isn't, which schema to use? Does Jon have access to your database? If YOU have access to the database, it shouldn't be difficult for YOU to find out. In any case, if a table with the name Employer didn't exist in SYS, you would get an error message, you wouldn't get a row count of zero - assuming that is ALL your code, and you didn't "handle" the error in some unhealthy way (which unfortunately is quite common).